# SQL Trigger statement errors

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

Syntax errors appearing on this trigger statement and I am unsure why. Had different views on it but the common error appears on line 3 of the code. Other times I have been told there are errors on lines 3,4 and 5. Where should I be looking for errors within this for it to work?

```
CREATE TABLE audit (
     id INT 
    current_username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    system_date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, 
    grade_change TINYINT DEFAULT NULL, 
    action VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)  
)   ENGINE=INNODB; 


DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER grade_audit 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON take 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO audit 
            SET action = ‘update’, 
            current_username = xxx, 
            grade_change = OLD.grade, 
            system_date = NOW(); 
        END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Does the `id INT` need a comma following it? That seems to be the case elsewhere.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Non ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on `ENGINE=INNODB;`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some commas:

```
id INT 
action VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL
```

Also you seem to be using some windows single quotes, which will fail in some environments:

```
SET action = ‘update’,
```